# IK Pole Target directing to wrong direction

Tags: bones, inverse-kinematics, axis

I have no idea why the pole doesn't follow the target, instead, the pole avoid it, i've tried to ROLL the bone to 0 degree. The result still the same.[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about your goals and problems with this rig and show your IK settings?

Comment: Usually IK pole must've directing to the target, but this done the opposite.